# How can i add to a List<Bitmap> also strings?

Tags: unity, c#

In the top i have:

```
private Dictionary<String, List<Point>> pointsList;
private List<Bitmap> Scales = new List<Bitmap>();
```

Then in the constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Scales.Count; i++)
        {
            CreateArray(Scales[i]);
        }
```

Then the method CreateArray:

```
private unsafe void CreateArray(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        bool[,] bwValues = new bool[bmp.Height, bmp.Width];

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);

        byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;

        int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            var row = ptr + (y * bmpData.Stride);

            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                var pixel = row + x * 4;

                bool isWhite = (pixel[0] == 255 &&
                                pixel[1] == 255 &&
                                pixel[2] == 255 &&
                                pixel[3] == 255);

                bwValues[y, x] = isWhite;

                if (isWhite == true)
                {
                    pointsList["GroupName"].Add(new Point(y, x));
                    //pointsList.Add(new Point(y, x));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where i want to group the Point List:

```
pointsList["GroupName"].Add(new Point(y, x));
```

Then i'm looping over the pointsList:

```
for (int x = 0; x < pointsList.Count; x++)
        {
            GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            cube.transform.parent = transform;
            cube.transform.position = new Vector3(-pointsList[x].Y, 0, pointsList[x].X);
        }
```

When looping over the pointsList i want to create a prefab of each group of Points. "Group 1" then the points in the list from "Group 2" another prefab.

But i have like 100 Bitmaps in the List i want somehow to separate them to groups in the List for example by string numbers so each numbers of Bitmaps to add "1" then "2" then "3" or maybe "Group 1" and "Group 2" and "Group 3" then i want to be able to read each Group of Bitmaps for example all the Bitmaps from Group 2 to Group 3.

Comment: What systems need to interact with this grouping? For instance, if you're in Unity, is the grouping an ease-of-use aid for humans working with the Inspector interface? Or is it being used by a streaming system to load blocks of related bitmaps at a time, or something else? Knowing more about the function the groups serve will help narrow down what representations will serve best.

Comment: @DMGregory you right it's also connected with unity i didn't mention it before since the Grouping is only in csharp but i forgot that i want to loop over the pointsList later and to create prefab of each Group of points. Now i'm looping over all the pointsList(Before it was not Dictionary just List<Point> but now i want to loop over each Group in pointsList and to make prefab of each Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the bitmaps into lists that you key by a string:

```
private Dictionary<String, List<Bitmap>> tests;
```

Comment: I tried this so i did in a loop: pointsList.Add(Group.ToString("D6"), new Point(y, x)); The type is Point not Bitmap but the problem is with the string why i'm getting error when doing "D6" ?  cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: So the addition process for a dictionary like this looks a little different, as you first need to initialize the list with `dictionary.Add("GroupName", new List<Bitmap>());` and then to add to the list you'd do `dictionary["GroupName"].Add(yourBitmap);`. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `Group.ToString`.